# What is more efficient for a image gallery in hybrid application

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am going to develop a hybrid app for image/videos gallery where I will be having 70-100 images/videos.

I am concerned about the efficiency of Jquery mobile.

Should I use Angularjs and Bootstrap or go with Jquery mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Angularjs with [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) - great framework for hybrid applications.